# Angular 2 Ngrx Store, Effects and "Ephemeral States"

Tags: angular, ngrx

Working in the context of a form component:

I am trying to show the states of the form to the user "pending, success, error, pristine". I don't want to have those states in the store as they are "ephemeral states".

I have  an Effect:

```
@Effect()
  addTagToVideoEffect_ = this.appState_
    .ofType(TagActions.ADD_TAG_TO_VIDEO)
    .map<AddTagToVideo>(action => action.payload)
    .switchMap((addTag: AddTagToVideo) => this.dtsiVideosService.addTagToVideo(addTag)
      .map((addTag: AddTagToVideo) => TagReducers.addTagToVideoComplete(addTag))
      .catch((err) =>Observable.throw(err))
    );
```

and in my form component I am dispatching the `TagActions.ADD_TAG_TO_VIDEO`  and subscribing to it:

```
onTag(tag: TagEntity) {

    this.subscription = this.tagActions.addTagToVideoEffect_.subscribe(
      this.onAddTagSuccess,
      this.onAddTagError
    );

    this.tagActions.addTagToVideo({videoId: this.videoId, tag: tag});
}
```

the `.tagActions.addTagToVideoEffect_.subscribe` results in having my effect called twice. How can we get the results of the effects in the view without passing by the store for all those ephemeral states ? And not having the effect called twice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get the effect call twice is because its only an Observable. You need to turn it into a Publisher.

```
@Effect()
  addTagToVideoEffect_ = this.appState_
    .ofType(TagActions.ADD_TAG_TO_VIDEO)
    .map<AddTagToVideo>(action => action.payload)
    .switchMap((addTag: AddTagToVideo) => this.dtsiVideosService.addTagToVideo(addTag)
      .map((addTag: AddTagToVideo) => TagReducers.addTagToVideoComplete(addTag))
      .catch((err) => Observable.throw(err))))
    .share();
```

Then you can work with it in your view:

```
tagFormState_: BehaviorSubject<FormState> = new BehaviorSubject<FormState>({});


  onTag(tag: TagEntity) {

  Observable.from(this.tagActions2.addTagToVideoEffect_)
  .first()
  .toPromise()
  .then(this.onAddTagSuccess, this.onAddTagError)

    this.tagFormState_.next({pending: true});
    this.tagActions.addTagToVideo({videoId: this.videoId, tag: tag});
  }


  onAddTagSuccess = (payload) => {
    this.tagFormState_.next({success: 'Success !'});
    this.resetTagFormState();
  }

  onAddTagError = (err) => {
    this.tagFormState_.next({error: err.message});
    this.resetTagFormState();
  }

  resetTagFormState() {
    setTimeout(_=> {
      this.tagFormState_.next({});
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Resources on the subject that helped me sort this out:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/1135
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1420
- https://egghead.io/courses/rxjs-subjects-and-multicasting-operators

Comment: So, you're saying that `.publish().refCount()` is required for all effects? What's the rule?

Comment: here is a deeper conversation on the subject: https://github.com/ngrx/effects/issues/59

Comment: I use this when the view needs to show the ephemeral results of the effect and I don't want or need those state in the store. Plus it cuts on a lot of boilerplate Action Effects Reducers :)

Comment: the problem is also experienced in other frameworks that adopts Redux patterns http://goshakkk.name/should-i-put-form-state-into-redux/